# Divide by zero error if diagonal elements are 0 in doolittle algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, matrix, divide-by-zero

So, I am trying to create a code which does LU Decomposition of a matrix by doolittle algorithm in python.
However, I am getting a divide by zero error if my diagonal elements are zero.
For example, when i tried solving this as my input matrix:
A = [[0 2 8 6] [0 0 1 2] [0 1 0 1] [3 7 1 0]]
I get a "divide by zero error" as my diagonal elements are zero.
Is it a limitation of doolittle algorithm?
What can I do to solve it?

P.S:- I know why I am getting the "divide by zero error", what I want to know is, what can I do now?
My code So far:

```
#Function to read the file and getting numbers in a Matrix
def file_opener(file_name):
    Matrix = []
    with open(file_name) as file:
        M_string = file.readlines()
    for line in M_string:
        Matrix.append(list(map(lambda i: int(i), line.split(" "))))
    return Matrix

#Function to create Identity Matrix
def identity(n):
    I = [[0 for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        I[i][i] = 1
    return I


#Function for LU decomposition
#Both L and U are directly kept together in A
#Note:- Diagonal elements of L should be 1 but are not stored in A
def luDecompose(A, n):
    for i in range(n):
        # Upper Triangle Matrix (i is row index, j is column index, k is summation index)
        for j in range(i,n):
            # Summation part
            sum = 0
            for k in range(i):
                if(i==k):
                    sum += A[k][j]  # Since diagonal elements of Lower matrix is 1
                else:
                    sum += A[i][k]*A[k][j]
        
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] - sum
        
        # Lower Triangle Matrix (j is row index, i is column index, k is summation index)
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            # Summation part
            sum = 0
            for k in range(i):
                if(j==k):
                    sum += A[k][i]  # Since diagonal elements of Lower matrix is 1
                else:
                    sum += A[j][k]*A[k][i]
            A[j][i] = (A[j][i] - sum)/A[i][i]


#Function for Forward-Backward Substitution
#Works in complimentary to LU Decomposition function
def forwardBackwardSubstitution(A,B,m,n):
    #Forward Substitution
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(m):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(i):
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
            B[i][j] = B[i][j] -  sum

    #Backward Substitution
    for j in range(n):
        for i in range(m-1,-1,-1):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(i+1,m):
                sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
            B[i][j] = (B[i][j] - sum)/A[i][i]


# The solving process starts here
A = file_opener("Matrix-A2.txt")
sizeA = len(A[0])

#Creating Identity matrix
I = identity(sizeA)

luDecompose(A,sizeA)
forwardBackwardSubstitution(A,I,sizeA,sizeA)
print(I)
```

Answer (score 2):

To initiate LU decomposition for a table that is not strictly diagonally dominant - or better put that one or more of its absolute diagonal values is not greater than the sum of the rest (includes the zero scenario), in that row - you would need to firstly permute it.

This way allows you to exchange rows in your initial A matrix and "imprint" them on a unit matrix (of same size to your A) by simultaneously permuting its rows. Thus you end up having PA = Pb, which extends to P(LU) = Pb where P is your unit permutation matrix where A = LU is your initial coefficient matrix and b is your initial vector. See the code below as an example of a permutation matrix:

```
#Permutation Matrix
import numpy as np

def permute(matrix):
    n = matrix.shape[0]
    U = matrix.copy()
    P = np.identity(n)
    for k in range(n):
        index = np.argmax(abs(U[k:,k]))
        index = index + k 
        if index != k:
            P = np.identity(n)
            P[[index,k],k:n] = P[[k,index],k:n]

    return P
```

I also urge you to have a look here at [LU factorization from University of Texas](https://johnfoster.pge.utexas.edu/numerical-methods-book/LinearAlgebra_LU.html), as well as in the book of Gilbert Strang "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" 4th edition, page 41, the subchapter "Row Exchanges and Permutation Matrices".